# Get all the tags of hierarichal struct in Go

Tags: go

I want to translate some fields of my Rest response from English to Hindi language. I have few translator files where I have mapping of words from English to Hindi. The name of the file I want to provide via field tags. 
So my struct will look something like this

```
    type myResponse struct {
        City string `translatorFile:"CityEToH"`
        State string `translatorFile:"StateEToH"`
        StationCode []string `translatorFile:"StationCodeEToH"`
        InsideStruct insideStruct
    }

    type insideStruct struct {
        trainName string `translatorFile:"TrainEToH"`
        StartingPoint string `translatorFile:"StationCodeEToH"`
        FinishPoint string `translatorFile:"StationCodeEToH"`
    }
```

I want to write a common translator method that will take interface{} as the input parameter and will return an interface (after converting the input) as output. I have just started to learn Go and I am stuck with the implementation. I am not able to create a map kind of structure that will map the fieldName to the corresponding translator file Name.

I have tried reflect.typeOf(input), but with this I am not able to get the tags of insideStruct. This is just an example structure of payload, I could have 4-5 inherited level of struct as well.

Is there a way to get the fieldName, tags and fieldValue together. Or is there any other better way to implement this ?

Comment: Show what you tried so far.

Comment: Get the type of object using `t:=reflect.TypeOf(obj)`, if it is struct, iterate fields using `fld:=t.FieldByIndex`, and use `fld.Tag.Get` to access the tags.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Tried unmarshal to convert struct to interface(for parsing input) but I lost the tags. After  that I tried to write a recursive method to iterate over the input and create a mapping between field and translator file. In this method I have interface{} as the input parameter. I am iterating over the fields (reflect.TypeOf(input).NumField()) and checking the type.  For type string I am putting the tag detail in map and for type reflect.Struct I am calling the same method with argument as reflect.TypeOf(input) (let's ignore other type like slice for now). This not working for insideSt

Comment: Write your recursive function to get a `reflect.Type`, so you can call it easily when you discover struct fields. At the top level, call it with `myFunc(reflect.TypeOf(myStruct{}))`

Comment: A hack worth checking is to use `json:"UniqKey"` and then use strings.ReplaceAll(marshalOutput, "UniqKey", "HindiKey") on the marshal output. I also thing its a good start to compare against benchmarks compare to  implementing tags for example

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that walks through values and calls a function for each string with the associated struct tag:

```
func walkStrings(v reflect.Value, tag reflect.StructTag, fn func(reflect.Value, reflect.StructTag)) {
    v = reflect.Indirect(v)
    switch v.Kind() {
    case reflect.Struct:
        t := v.Type()
        for i := 0; i < t.NumField(); i++ {
            walkStrings(v.Field(i), t.Field(i).Tag, fn)
        }
    case reflect.Slice, reflect.Array:
        if v.Type().Elem().Kind() == reflect.String {
            for i := 0; i < v.Len(); i++ {
                walkStrings(v.Index(i), tag, fn)
            }
        }
    case reflect.String:
        fn(v, tag)
    }
}
```

The function `fn` can use [Value.String](https://godoc.org/reflect#Value.String) to get the value as a string and [Value.SetString](https://godoc.org/reflect#Value.SetString) to change the value.   Use [StructTag.Get](https://godoc.org/reflect#StructTag.Get) to get the tag. An example function is:

```
func translate(v reflect.Value, tag reflect.StructTag) {
    if !v.CanSet() {
        // unexported fields cannot be set
        return
    }
    file := tag.Get("translatorFile")
    if file == "" {
        return
    }
    v.SetString(translatStringWithFile(v.String(), file)
}
```

Call `walkStrings` with a reflect.Value of a struct pointer and the empty string as the tag:

```
v := myResponse{
    City:         "mycity",
    StationCode:  []string{"code1", "code2"},
    InsideStruct: insideStruct{"trainname", "start", "finish"},
}
walkStrings(reflect.ValueOf(&v), "", translate)
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/iMXokhB9W0R).